# Using sed to replace a string that has parentheses and double-quotes

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to replace the following string with null/nothing using sed:

`(env "MyValue")`

I've tried a bunch of escapes like this but can't get it to work,

`sed -i -e "s|"\(\env \"\MyValue\"\\)\"|""|g" ./myFile`

Any sed gods here that can direct me? I cannot seem (with many many different attempts, to get sed to remove the above string from my files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier if you enclose sed script in single quotes:

```
$ cat myFile
abc (env "MyValue") def
$ sed -i 's/(env "MyValue")//g' myFile
$ cat myFile
abc  def
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect! I will accept the answer in 8 mins when I can... can you suggest somewhere I can learn sed that's a good read? I don't want to suck with it anymore...

Comment: You say you're on Linux so you most probably use GNU sed - read its manual, it's short https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/. Additionally, since sed is most commonly used in shell scripts and you come across issues such as this one you should read your shell manual.

Comment: I just read that when using double quotes, your string is going to be interpreted by the shell... got it thanks again

Comment: @Woodstock I like this one: [Grymoire](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) - please note: in your original try, you escaped the parentheses `\(` -> Actually escaping them makes them special for grouping, while NOT escaping them just matches the character.

Comment: note that if you run that script in a file in which the subject of the regexp is alone on the line sed will replace it with an empty line.